# Webform custom submit button

Tags: webforms, forms

Hy,

If someone can help me with an idea. I have a second button on my webform with an specific handler. Everything it's OK it execute my function but I want that this button to also save in the db of drupal like the first button. But only the first button do that. I don't understand why. I must to set something special in the definition of this button to do that?

Here is how I created my buttons:

```
array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'decla_form_submit');
unset($form['actions']['submit']);

if ($declaLineOrigin[0] -> CLOSED == 'N') {
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Recalculer'),
        '#validate' => array('decla_validate'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_decla_button_div">',
        '#weight' => 50,
    );

    $form['actions']['validation'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Valider'),
        '#submit' => array('decla_form_validation_submit'),
        '#executes_submit_callback' => TRUE,
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#weight' => 70,
    );
}
```

Is the "Valider" button.
The div is for an ajax call ... I want to hide this button if an specify textfield change.

```
$form['submitted']['declaration_fieldset']['base_trimestre']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => 'decla_fire_callback',
    'wrapper' => array('replace_decla_button_div'),
    'event' => 'click',
    // 'event' => 'input',
    'progress' => 'none',
);
```

Thank you everyone and have nice day !

Comment: I don't understand your question: when you click "Valider" button, the function decla_form_validation_submit is not called? And this is the problem?

Comment: Also you said, that you want to hide "Valider" button, when something is changed in a textfield. What textfield? I don't see anything about that in the code. Anyway, it can be easily done via javascript.

Comment: Thank you. decla_form_validation_submit is called and it's works fine. But the form it's not saved in the drupal db like when you click on submit. You can't see the results in results area of webform. I need this to fill a pdf whith fillpdf.

Comment: To hide the button I use an ajax on my textfield and it's work. The only problem is that I set the event on my ajax to 'click' and it's called every time when you click on the textfield. It was much better to do that using un event like 'change' but I don't now how to set up un delay, because ajax it's fired every time you change samething. Normaly you must to have an delay after you changed the value and the ajax is fired. If you have an ideea .... :)

Comment: Maybe, for the textfield, you can use onBlur event, that fires, when the cursor leaves the text input? In that function you'll need to check, whether the user changed something.

Comment: "But the form it's not saved in the drupal db like when you click on submit." - please, show `decla_form_validation_submit` function code in your question. So I could see, why the form is not saved.

Comment: `function decla_trim_form_validation_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $owner = $form_state['values']['submitted']['decla_trim_owner'];
    $svc = prepareWriteClass();
    $query = $svc -> EntDecla() -> filter("id eq " . $owner);
    $customer = $query -> Execute() -> Result[0];
    $customer -> type = 'Y';
    setupTraceInfos($customer);
    $svc -> UpdateObject($customer);
    $svc -> SaveChanges();
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
`

Comment: Try to `var_dump($owner);exit;` in `decla_trim_form_validation_submit` function after you get the owner.

Comment: Nothing change. The form is not inserted in drupal db. All the values is there ... just my button who don't have the name 'submit' ... I don't now ....

Comment: I didn't expect anything to change. I wanted to see, whether you get any data. In order to fix the problem, we must get the information about it first.

Comment: Yes I'm inside the function the owner is present. `string '3279351100' (length=10)`

Comment: In this case check, whether it returns you the correct $customer object by calling `var_dump($customer);`

Comment: Yes. No problem here. I have my customer and can alter and save.

Comment: So, you have a good object, but for some reason it doesn't save anything to the database, when you call `$svc -> UpdateObject($customer);`?

Comment: Thanks but you misunderstood. "But the form it's not saved in the drupal db like when you click on submit" . In fact the default submit function of webform it's not called on the second button. Only my own function declared by `'#submit' => array('decla_form_validation_submit')` . If the default submit function of webform it's not called then the values of this form it's not saved in DRUPAL DB (not in my db by own function)

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to help you without narrowing down the problem. This discussion is already too big.